# Difference at assembly level of printf from cstdio and iostream

Tags: c++, c, io

So this question is just out of curiosity.
I have some tiny program:

```
#include <some_header>
void print(){ printf("abc"); } // don't care about main, I'm not gonna run it
```

Then I compiled it to assembly, with once `some_header`=>`iostream` and another time `some_header`=>`cstdio` with gcc.godbolt.org (6.1 for x86_64) with `-O3 -pedantic -std=c++14`. Look at this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "abc"
print(): (iostream) or (both included)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     printf
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
        movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
print(): (cstdio)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     printf
```

There's a significant difference between them, and they're identical for the first three lines, so why do `iostream` need such amount of code to clean up or what are those lines just doing? OR just to say that godbolt is unreliable upon this task?

---

Also it seems that standard doesn't guarantee that printf is accessible from `iostream`, should this be relied upon?

Comment: The bits after `jmp` are not part of that function. They're part of another function which for some reason isn't labelled.

Comment: @immibis Ah, I should have noticed that, but it's just interesting that even if I only include `iostream`, that part of code exist even with `-Os`, so I suspect that's some dynamic initializer or something alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print function compiles to a pretty much the same assembly code in both cases.
The additional lines you see are to initialise and de-initialise iostream library. You may see that clearly if you remove the optimisation flag `-O3`.
Here is a complete listing with iostream included and optimisation switched off.

```
std::piecewise_construct:
        .zero   1
.LC0:
        .string "abc"
print():
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
        cmpl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        jne     .L4
        cmpl    $65535, -8(%rbp)
        jne     .L4
        movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
        movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
        call    __cxa_atexit
.L4:
        nop
        leave
        ret
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $65535, %esi
        movl    $1, %edi
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Is that compulsory whenever I include `iostream`?

Comment: @YiFei That's what the particular implementation of the library does. Another implementation may behave differently. C++ standard doesn't specify these kind of implementation details.